# Is there any crash that not related to signal

Tags: linux

Usually a crash report in Linux could look like this below:

```
[jack-VirtualBox:14564] *** Process received signal ***
[jack-VirtualBox:14564] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[jack-VirtualBox:14564] Signal code:  (-6)
[jack-VirtualBox:14564] Failing at address: 0x3e8000038e4
[jack-VirtualBox:14564] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f1c048f0390]
[jack-VirtualBox:14564] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(raise+0x29)[0x7f1c048f0269]
[jack-VirtualBox:14564] [ 2] ../test/send_recv[0x400b6c]
[jack-VirtualBox:14564] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f1c04535830]
[jack-VirtualBox:14564] [ 4] ../test/send_recv[0x4009d9]
[jack-VirtualBox:14564] *** End of error message ***
```

One program does something unexpected by software or hardware. A signal is sent to that program, (1) signal handled by signal handler (2) no signal handler registered, default handler triggered.

So it looks like all crash and hang of program is related to signal. Is there any possibility that a crash or hang is not caused by a signal?

Comment: Some signals are the kernel's way to signal that a program needs to be terminated (and why). But that signal only happens when something else went wrong before, like accessing a bad memory location. The signal is just the messenger, not the cause. Also note that not every signal means a crash, `SIG_CHILD` notifies a parent process that a child process has terminated. Many daemons treat `SIG_HUP` as a command to reload their configuration. All bets are off for `SIG_USR1` and `SIG_USR2`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on how you define *crash* and *hang*.

I would define *crash* as an abnormal situation that makes your program stop.
And *hang* is an abnormal situation that makes your program unable to work properly.

For example, you can consider that code equivalent to this:

```
while (true) ;
```

is actually a hang, even when the process is not finished and no signal is raised.

Note that you do not need to write an infinite loop literally. For example, code like:

```
int y = ...;
for (unsigned char x = 0; x < y; ++x)
{ /*...*/ }
```

will *hang* if `y` happens to be bigger than 255.

About crashes, in C++ you can write:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        return real_main();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "unhandled exception" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then, any unexpected exception will finish the program, but it will not raise any signal either. Is this a crash? It certainly looks like one...

Other example:

```
void *safe_malloc(size_t sz)
{
    void *m = malloc(sz);
    if (m == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory error\n");
        exit(99);
    }
    return m;
}
#define malloc safe_malloc
```

Now, a `malloc` failure will *crash* without raising signal.

PS: Maybe I should call `abort()` instead of `exit(99)`, but `abort()` actually raises `SIGABRT`, so it would break my example.

Answer (score 0):

There are some crashes that are not caused by a signal. In Linux these happen when the OS decides that your process must die.

- kill -9 [pid]
  Someone sent SIGKILL. This isn't a real signal. The operating system just terminates your program with extreme prejudice.
- OOM (Out of Memory)
  The system is out of memory but something is demanding more. If Linux was using over-commit, it promised more memory it can deliver. So it kills something. It might be your program. It tends to select the largest memory users so if you have a memory leak, you might get this "crash" rather often. There's no signal. Just death.

Comment: `kill -9` does send the KILL signal to the process.